# Android playing http video via Intent - passing http headers

Tags: java, android, eclipse, http, video

I want to play video via Intent. The video uri is a http link to mp4 video. The server requires a special HTTP header token. How to pass via Intent a special HTTP headers to video player so that it includes it to the http requests it makes to server. Is there a standard way? Below is the code I use to play video via Intent.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videoPlaybackUrl));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(videoPlaybackUrl), "video/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to pass via Intent a special HTTP headers to video player so that it includes it to the http requests it makes to server. Is there a standard way?

If you wrote the "video player", you can come up with your own set of extra keys for passing this information.

However, you are using `ACTION_VIEW`, which means that you have no assurances over who wrote the video player. There is no "standard way" to ask responders to `ACTION_VIEW` to add HTTP headers to their stream request.

Comment: It is not so obvious that there is not a standard way to pass HTTP headers. Intent system was design to pass fancy parameters to Activities. I will wait - maybe someone else will answer.

Comment: @cubesoft: You will be waiting a very long time.

Comment: Hehe. Ok. You are right. I ended up implementing my own video player on top of android MediaPlayer class which has a method for setting a video source with http headers. Anyway thanks for prompt responses.